# join query with select distinct in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :work
end

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

I need to have distinct description from Work table for specific country's users
I have written following query

```
Work.includes(:user).where("users.country_name = ?",'IN').select("distinct works.description").limit(10)
```

It works but it does not give me distinct works.description

Comment: If your `users` table doesn't have `description` column you can replace `distinct works.description` with `distinct description` and it should work. Otherwise you can give `works.description` an alias using smth like `distinct works.description as work_descr` and then get the value as `result[0].work_descr`. Note, that result of this query is an array, so you should call `work_descr` (or `description` in the 1st case) on its elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked with following query,

```
Work.includes(:user).where("users.country_name = ?",'IN').group("works.description").limit(10)
```